# Get Google API refresh Token using API Key

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, api-key, refresh-token

Sorry I'm noob does google have API to obtain new refresh token using API keys? Thanks!

I expect to get Google refresh token using API Key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have miss understood something about how Authorization works.

Api Keys give you access to public data only.

To access private user data you need an access token and a refresh token.  You must request authorization of the user who owns the data.  using Oauth2. using your client id and client secret.

You can not get a refresh token using an api key.

You may want to check the documentation [oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)